# How do I feed items into a multifarm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

I have a multifarm set up, and it has a pipe connector on the bottom. Immediately upon connecting a pipe, items were ejected. How can I connect a pipe to use as input only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the wiki page on [Multifarms](http://forestry.sengir.net/wiki.new/doku.php?id=farms:multi), the bottom is for output only. Inputs have to be piped in through a Farm Hatch.

Comment: So I'm piping out through a farm hatch in the bottom, should I pipe in through a farm hatch in the top?

Comment: I don't have one set up so I can't confirm, but it sounds like the output is automatic (which matches other Forestry machines) and doesn't need a Hatch, while a Hatch on the side or top is necessary for input. (Side/top may also determine the interior slot items go to.)

Comment: You can pipe into the side, and the farm ejects out of the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've got one working as well. Here's what I can tell, since the wiki seems unclear:

It appears the MultiFarm knows where to place the items pumped into it through a Farm Hatch no matter where said Hatch is placed. In other words, the Hatches send the current "crop's" "soil" to the the inside-uppper-right slot, seeds or saplings go in the upper-right slot, Fertilizer in the bottom center slot, etc.

It will also output the harvested items that it does not use* into pipes/inventories connected to the bottom of the Farm Block structure OR into powered Wooden Transport Pipes attached to a non-inputting Farm Hatch - just like any other BuildCraftesque machine!

*That is, as opposed to items like Seeds from Wheat Harvests, which go right back in the upper-right-slot automatically.

Looking into information about Circuit Boards next...these MultiFarms are a lot of work to set up.

Comment: So when you say you've got one working, you mean a MultiFarm and not a manager?

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure you can output from the farm hatch.